# Jquery validation not required field tooltip message issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation and to show the error messages using the bootstrap tooltips. This works fine, but when I insert an incorrect value in a not required field, and then delete the text and leave the field empty, the highlight effect in the input disappears but the tooltip remains visible.

JS

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
  onkeyup: false,
  rules: {
    field1: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    },
    field2: {
      number: true
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
        newError = $(error).text();
    $(element).data('lastError', newError);
    if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
      $(element).tooltip({
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "manual"
      }).attr('title', newError).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
    }
  },
  success: function (label, element) {
    $(element).tooltip('hide');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="field1" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

To solve my problem I try to use **unhighlight** method, but only works the first time, then the tooltip is no longer displayed when re-insert an incorrect value in the same field

```
 unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    $(element).tooltip('hide');
 }
```

Type text in the 2nd field and than delete it.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ene93oo9/)

How can I solve my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be considered a hack-job, but listening to the `blur` event and clearing the tooltip if empty, works perfectly:

```
$("input").blur(function () {
  if (!this.value.trim().length)
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
  onkeyup: false,
  rules: {
    field1: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    },
    field2: {
      required: false,
      number: true
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
        newError = $(error).text();
    $(element).data('lastError', newError);
    if (newError !== '') {
      $(element).tooltip({
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "manual"
      }).attr('title', newError).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
    }
  },
  success: function(label, element) {
    $(element).tooltip('hide');
  }
});
$("input").blur(function() {
  if (!this.value.trim().length)
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```

```css
#myform {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="field1" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reo1ck3e/**

Comment: Unfortunately only works the first time, then the tooltip is no longer displayed when re-insert an incorrect value in the same field

Comment: @PaoloRossi Removed this rule: ` && newError !== lastError` and it works. Kindly check.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!